# What does “ont retrouvé le travail” mean in this context?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

I came about this beginning of a sentence :

> Les Français ont **retrouvé** le travail depuis […]

When I wanted to check the meaning of **retrouvé**, I found many meanings. What does it mean in the context of the above sentence?

Comment: I edited your French :)

Comment: Where did you check, and what are the meanings you think might fit?

Comment: More context is necessary to appreciate the meaning of the word. Give at least the complete sentence from which you have extracted these word.

Comment: This few words don't really mean anything. It could be that the *le* is wrong, or that a word is missing after *le* but only the full context could bring you a hopefully correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

In this kind of context it would be mean that the French are back from holidays and getting ready to go back to work. The same verb is used when talking about kids going back to school: "les enfants/écoliers ont retrouvé le chemin de l'école".

Comment: *Retrouvé* sounds a little weird to me, however (though perfectly understandable). I would use *repris* in both cases.

Comment: *Repris* is a good synonym I could use to replace *retrouvé*.